# Typeahead: Return JSON array with multiple data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using bootstrap's typeahead and I'm wondering how I can return a JSON array with multiple pieces of data for each result.

For example, I want to be able to return two pieces of data for each result, the `name` and the `description`. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is using "Multiple Datasets" as mentioned in the following link:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets

You'll have to create 2 different sources: one for the "name" and one for the "description".

In case you don't want to search using the "description", then you can use the following code:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates
You'll be able to search using the "name" and the description will be displayed next to the name.

Answer (score 0):

This code will make the output to show result from two columns when you type. You have to change only in `search.php` code, not any other place. Try it and give feedback.

```
$key=$_GET['key'];  
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "yourbd");
/* check connection */
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
      exit();
  }
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from yourtb where yourcolumn LIKE '%{$key}%'");

 if (!$result) {
die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

             $rows[] = $r['col1']. ' - ' . $r['col2'];
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
```